# Is it possible to store a variable in a PHP script that's called by AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

Simple question: When I call an PHP script by AJAX - is it possible to store a variable for the next call(s)?

I would like to avoid using a cookie for this.

Comment: Next call in general or next call by the same user agent? Note that `$_SESSION` does use a cookie.

Comment: Actually I would prefer the next call in general. Good to know. Thought it's stored on server-side.

Comment: In that case store it in a database. There are other options but they are more likely to cause trouble for you later if you don't know what you are choosing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store data in a JavaScript variable. Second option, is to store data in database or a file. PHP `$_SESSION` variable should work too.

Comment: Can you explain the `$_SESSION` method? I've tried this but I'm not sure if I did it correct since it didn't work for me. I basically tried this     `if(!array_key_exists("foo", $_SESSION)) $_SESSION['foo'] = getFoo();`

Comment: @Brettetete have you called `session_start()` at the beginning of your php-file ? [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: @doc no. Was currently editing my comment since I've spotted the mistake already. #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling php code from AJAX function means your page is not refreshing so you can store the values in hidden field for next call. Or you want those values for another pages or after page refresh as well then you need to check with $_Session["Session_name"];

Thanks